# UWP Microsoft Ads in xbox

Tags: uwp, ads, banner, xbox, windows-dev-center

I am developing an app in UWP Platform and put some banners on this.
I am using PC/Tablet key and 300x50 banner size.

In PC I was check and it working ok. But I want to distribute the app in xbox too while I cant test with xbox.

Anybody can confirm with the way to show banner in xbox is correct or not?
(because in my App, mainly installtion is xbox but the counting of request Ads not as much as expected so I want to confirm the ads integration is correct or not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Xbox is Windows system, and the same as Windows. You may not deployed banner ad 300*50 size on your Xbox, this size should be used on your Windows Phone app.

You’d better use Windows 10 size on your Xbox, such as 300*250, and try it again.

**Please note** Real ApplicationId and AdUnitId value should apply from the published apps and it takes 1-2 days after that for ads from real units to start serving.

More detailed information about ad sizes, you can refer to [Supported ad size for banner ads.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/supported-ad-sizes-for-banner-ads)

Comment: Hi Cherry Bu
According to your document the banner 300*50 size only work in Window 10 Mobile.
But actually, when I run the app in PC it still working.
And can you tell me What version of OS running on xBox?

Comment: Hello, you'd better use **Windows 10(UWP) and Windows 8.1 ad size** on xBox, such as **300*250, 728*90, 160*600, 300*600**. According to the layout of the page, you could choose the most suitable size.